# MFC C++ VS 2010 : Edit Box to accept only alphabets, backspace and spaces

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

As mentioned in the title, I am currently using VS 2010 C++ , MFC application for my project. Currently new to programming.

I am currently asked to create an edit box to accept names, full names, e.g "Lee Roy Long". I have looked through many other websites but I am confused with which method should I use to do it.

Is there any examples or a guide to how to go about this?

EDIT: I have another question aside from this solved one [ Cannot Post new questions due to the "restrictions"], I am currently using the same edit box to add new names as strings into the SQLite database. I am currently having some trouble converting `CString` to `string`

```
vector<int> userSerialNumber;
vector<string> userName;
vector<int> userID;
vector<int> userTrainingImagesNo;
```

Program starts here:

```
     CString str,text;
     CString Lone = _T("MEEP"); // This one converts it succesffuly...
     string ss((CStringA(Lone)));/Only works for declared CStrings? 
     CEdit* editBox = (CEdit*)GetDlgItem(IDC_EDIT1);
     editBox->GetWindowText(str);
```

Adding the user's input from above into the program below.

```
            userSerialNumber.push_back(newserialnumber);
        userID.push_back(newserialnumber);
        userName.push_back(ss);
        userTrainingImagesNo.push_back(Img);
```

I have referred to many websites on how to convert CStrings to strings, but none of them worked, including this one.

As I debug the program, the conversion between CString and string did not work as I get "" for string, which causes the database to update a blank "".

CString str = "name";//Name CString gotten from EditBox
std::string newname = ""; //After typing many conversion methods, results ""

Is there something that I did not notice regarding this ?

Comment: Your title doesn't match the question. " backspace" is an edit key on your keyboard, not a character. Would you also accept arrow keys and Delete?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter the keystrokes going into the edit control by deriving a class from CEdit and handling the WM_CHAR message in your derived class. To accept a key pass it along to CEdit::OnChar, to reject a key simply return without calling the CEdit function.

To connect the edit control to your code you use a standard MFC subclassing technique. Right-click on the control and create a control member variable (a CEdit) in the parent window. Then edit to change the variable from a CEdit to a CYourDerivedCEdit.

There is a tutorial about this and a sample project at http://www.flounder.com/validating_edit_control.htm

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to trapping each character,  you can handle the [CWnd::OnKillFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8205kkwk.aspx) event for the edit box and interrogate the value **once**.  Validating can be done by using [CString::SpanExcluding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa300649(v=vs.60).aspx) with numbers and any other character that should **not** be in the resulting string.  For example,

```
CString stringEnteredByUser = _T("Lee Roy Long");
CString validatedString = stringEnteredByUser.SpanExcluding("0123456789");
if (stringEnteredByUser != validatedString)
   AfxMessageBox(_T("Invalid string"), MB_OK);
```

The 'stringEnteredByUser' variable should contain the string entered by the user.  In this example, using *SpanExcluding* will tell you if they've entered a number.  The returned string from the call (*validatedString*) will **not** match the string the user typed (*stringEnteredByUser*) if they've entered a character that is invalid (ie. the character is within the list provided to the *SpanExluding* call).

If the validatoin fails, simply force the focus back to the edit box.

Answer (score -3):

I'm assuming you know some basic event coding.

Use the `Textbox.textchanged` event.
Also research `ASCII` and its conversion (`asc` function.)
If you need any more help, comment below. 
Good luck!

Comment: This answer does not apply to an MFC app.